# Capturing dates in a right-to-left document

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture dates written in the following formats in an RTL (Hebrew) text:

DD/MM/YYYY

DD/MM/YY

DD.MM.YY

DD.MM.YYYY

DD-MM-YY

DD-MM-YYYY

The dates appear as separate words, or immediately after a hypen (-).
In the output text, I wanted to convert these texts to the [Month DD, YYYY] format.

So I tried writing the following expressions, where #days# and #month# are replacement lists:

```
(\b)(#days#)[\.-/](#month#)[\.-/](\d{2})[\b]
(-)(#days#)[\.-/](#month#)[\.-/](\d{2})[\b]
(\b)(#days#)[\.-/](#month#)[\.-/](\d{4})[\b]
(-)(#days#)[\.-/](#month#)[\.-/](\d{4})[\b]
```

With these formulas, only dates that are the only words in the string are captured. All other dates are not...

What did I write wrong in these expressions?
Thanks,

Comment: Try replacing `[\.-/]` with `[./-]` and `[\b]` with `\b`.

Comment: @Ilanysong hey can you provide date with the sample or demo one.?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
(?:-|\b)(?<day>\d{2})([-.\/])(?<month>\d{2})\2(?<year>\d{4}|\d{2})(?:-|\b)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/eX2pO1/1)

it starts and ends with `(?:-|\b)` as I am not sure what you mean 'immediately after a hypen' in right to left text.

Comment: Thank you - I will try this out and let you know if it works! :)